# Prove that Sequentially Compact Metric Spaces are Lindelöf without the Axiom of Choice.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, axiom-of-choice

A proof can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequentially_Compact_Metric_Space_is_Lindel%C3%B6f), but it seems that it uses AC. I would like to know if there is a proof for this fact without AC.

I came up with this question after seeing a proof of sequential compactness $\implies$ Compactness for metrizable topological spaces without using generalized [Lebesgue's Number Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) for sequentially compact metric spaces. Both proofs can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequentially_Compact_Metric_Space_is_Compact).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result cannot be proved without the axiom of choice.  For instance, let $X$ be an infinite set which contains no countably infinite subset (the existence of such a set is consistent with ZF), and give $X$ the discrete metric.  Then $X$ is sequentially compact since there are no sequences in $X$ which take infinitely many different values so every sequence has a constant subsequence.  But $X$ is not Lindelöf, since the open cover of $X$ by singletons has no countable subcover.

Comment: May I know how do we construct such X? Thanks.

Comment: That's a very long story if you're not familiar with forcing.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396679/86856 for a sketch of the construction; you can find the details, for instance, in Example 15.52 of Jech's _Set Theory_ (3rd edition).

Comment: That is indeed a good answer, but just curious, does the statement "sequential compactness implies compactness for metric spaces" rely on the axiom of countable choice? Is there a proof without it?

Comment: @WilliamSun: Since compact is stronger than Lindelöf, if you need choice to prove sequentially compact metric spaces are Lindelöf you also need it to prove they are compact.

Comment: @WilliamSun In fact, for pseudometric spaces the implication "sequentially compact $\Rightarrow$ compact" has been shown to be equivalent to countable choice by Herrlich and Bentley https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864197001387 For metric spaces, the situation is more difficult. I think Kyriakos Keremedis has a paper out that treats this but I'm not sure.